# calling a controller when pressing button

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to add a new button which is for returning a used card. I am not sure why the data is not being sent with the request.
here is my index.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('assignees.destroy',$assignee->id) }}" method="POST">
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('assignees.show',$assignee->id) }}">Show</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('assignees.edit',$assignee->id) }}">Edit</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('returncard',$assignee->id) }}">Return Card</a>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
```

and here is my controller where I am defining the return card route:

```
public function returncard(assignee $assignee)
          {
              //
              $assignee->timeout = now();
              $assignee->update();

                return redirect()->route('assignees.index')
                                ->with('success','assignee updated successfully');
          }
```

web.php:

```
Route::resource('assignees','AssigneeController');
Route::get('autocomplete', 'AssigneeController@autocomplete')->name('autocomplete');
Route::get('searchcard', 'AssigneeController@searchcard')->name('searchcard');
Route::get('returncard', 'AssigneeController@returncard')->name('returncard');
```

output of dd($assignee)

```
Assignee {#266 ▼
  #fillable: array:9 [▼
    0 => "cabinet"
    1 => "custidno"
    2 => "timein"
    3 => "timeout"
    4 => "refnumber"
    5 => "cardno"
    6 => "refnumber"
    7 => "entrytype"
    8 => "notes"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

when pressing any button nothing is happening and the timeout is not being updated.

Comment: Can you copy the generated html?

Comment: What have you checked so far? I would suggest putting a dd($assignee) in the controller to see if you are passing what you expect. However, I can see that you are only passing the id of the assignee. As the controller is linked to a model (assignee), you should be passing an assignee object. Try removing the ->id from the {{ route('returncard',$assignee->id) }}. Or.... continue to pass only the id and add $assignee = assignee::findorfail($id); to the top of the controller and change returncard(assignee $assignee) to returncard($id)

Comment: Not completely up to date with the new Blade directives, but looks suspicious you having a `POST` method and a directive for `DELETE` method

Comment: @DiogoSanto HTML forms don't support delete, put, patch requests so that's normal.

Comment: @Devon thank you for the insight, good Sir! :)

Comment: @Petay87 when adding "$assignee - assignee::findorfail($id) "
I am getting "Undefined variable: id"
when hard coding "1" into the find or fail function it is updating the timeout column.

Comment: @Abdul did you change the function name to public function returncard($id)?

Comment: can we get the code from the routes file too?

Comment: why is your class in lover letter and what does dd($assignee); give you when you add it at the beginning of the returncard method? BTW returncard should be returnCard. Keep the laravel standard

Comment: @Petay87 I did, I got too few arguments exception.

Comment: @Indra I will add the output of dd  and routes to the question now.

Comment: @Abdul try using carbon here: instead of $assignee->timeout = now(); do $assignee->timeout = Carbon\Carbon::now(); Take a look at that. It's wonderful library and it also help with internationalization. or even better if timeout if in fillable in your model do one line: $assignee->update(['timeout' => Carbon\Carbon::now()]);

Comment: if dd($asignee) worked this means your button works so I would check the redirect

Answer (score 0):

You need add a parameter in your route if you're trying to pass the assignee ID to the controller method:

```
Route::get('returncard/{assignee}', 'AssigneeController@returncard')->name('returncard');
```

The resource routes handle this for you, the specific routes (GET,POST,etc) do not.  If you're using Route Model Binding, you need to make sure this parameter matches the argument name of your method.

I suggest you read the Laravel docs and follow the outlined naming conventions if you're working in the framework as Indra suggested in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::get('assignees/autocomplete/{assignees}', 'AssigneeController@autocomplete')->name('autocomplete');
Route::get('assignees/searchcard/{assignees}', 'AssigneeController@searchcard')->name('searchcard');
Route::get('assignees/returncard/{assignees}', 'AssigneeController@returncard')->name('returncard');

Route::resource('assignees','AssigneeController');
```

**Change the routes like that then it will be working.**

**if you are creating own function in resource then you must to use route of that function before the resource route**

Comment: yup you can do that as well

Comment: It's still lacking since the routes still don't provide a parameter for the assignee id.  There actually wasn't any problem with the OP's placement of routes since they didn't use the assignees prefix.